# Do Redis's GetDatabase() method caches all database tables?

Tags: c#, caching, redis

I have cached my database using following code for Redis operations:

```
  public bool InitialiseCache()
    {
        try
        {
            _cache = Connection.GetDatabase();                
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I tried to debug and preview value of `_cache` but it does not display cached data (tables). I wanted to confirm that `GetDatabase()` method caches all tables. Is there any way to preview all Redis keys, or values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer :**

No, Redis's GetDatabase() method **DOES NOT caches all database tables**

**Long Answer :**

As Per [StackExchange.Redis on Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md#using-a-redis-database) :

> **Using a redis database**
>
> Accessing a redis database is as simple as:
>
> ```
> IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
> ```
>
> **The object returned from GetDatabase is a cheap pass-thru object, and does not need to be stored.** Note that redis supports multiple
>   databases (although this is not supported on "cluster"); this can be
>   optionally specified in the call to GetDatabase. Additionally, if you
>   plan to make use of the asynchronous API and you require the
>   [Task.AsyncState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.asyncstate(v=vs.110).aspx) to have a value, this can also be specified:
>
> ```
> int databaseNumber = ...
> object asyncState = ...
> IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(databaseNumber, asyncState);
> ```
>
> Once you have the IDatabase, it is simply a case of using the [redis
>   API](http://redis.io/commands). Note that all methods have both synchronous and asynchronous
>   implementations. In line with Microsoft's naming guidance, the
>   asynchronous methods all end ...Async(...), and are fully await-able
>   etc.